# Is length of Digital Signature is digital token(digital certificate) dependent?

Tags: java, digital-signature, x509certificate, keystore

Is length of Digital Signature is digital token(digital certificate) dependent? I am generating digital signature using following code and length of digital signature varies from certificate to certificate. Length is unique for all certificates or is it certificate dependent? I am using ePass digital token.

```
 Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
                                        try {
                                            Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(DIGEST_SHA1);
                                            signature.initSign(privateKey);
                                            signature.update("abc".getBytes("UTF-8"));

                                        //  X509Certificate certFromKeystore = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(signName);
                                            X509Certificate certFromKeystore = x509CertificateToSign;
                                            // System.out.println(alias+"***"+certFromKeystore.toString());
                                            List certList = new ArrayList();
                                            CMSTypedData data = new CMSProcessableByteArray("abc".getBytes());
                                            certList.add(certFromKeystore);
                                            Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);
                                            CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
                                            ContentSigner sha1Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(DIGEST_SHA1)
                                                    .setProvider("SunMSCAPI").build(privateKey);
                                            gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(
                                                    new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider(BC_PROVIDER).build())
                                                            .build(sha1Signer, certFromKeystore));
                                            gen.addCertificates(certs);
                                            CMSSignedData signedData = gen.generate(data, false);
                                            BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
                                            String signedContent = encoder.encode((byte[]) signedData.getSignedContent().getContent());
                                            System.out.println(
                                                    "=============Signed content:=============" + "\n" + signedContent + "\n");
                                            String envelopedData = encoder.encode(signedData.getEncoded());
                                            System.out.println("==============Enveloped data===============" + "\n"
                                                    + envelopedData + "==" + envelopedData.length());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the digital signature format you are using.

A basic signature container (i. e. PKCS#1) includes only the signed hash. An advanced format can include the certficate itself too or a reference to the certificate.

In your case, CMS, you are including the certificate, so the size of the result will be different for each one